# Which SQL server is running on a Linux Box?

Tags: sql, linux, redhat

I have a redhat linux server that I am trying to work out what is running on it.  I have inherited it and am trying to move it to a different server.

I know there are several SQL databases running on it but I don't know what SQL package is controlling them.

Is there a way to find out?

Comment: This really belongs on serverfault, but I dont have choice to migrate to there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Red Hat `services` command to get a list of daemons running. One of them should be the database server.

```
sudo service --status-all
```

And if that doesn't work (e.g. it's not being run as a service) you can always do

```
ps -ef|grep 'postgres|mysql|oracle|sql'
```